# Water is coming out from shower hose every time I use water in any part of my house

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, shower, boiler

1. The shower water seem to have a life of it’s own.It is not stopping regardless. When using the sink or washing machine, even the kitchen sink, the shower stream changes dynamicly with a pumping sound.
2. when using the sink, the shower goes on and when I turn the sink tap off, the shower stops.
3. when I turn on the kitchen sink or use the washing machine, water from the shower hose is coming out, but the problem is, when I turn off the water at the kitchen sink, water from shower hose doesn't stop. I need to go to the bathroom and turn on and off the bathroom sink to stop water at shower hose.

So the only way to stop water from shower hose is turning on and off bathroom sink.

Comment: Don’t bring the horse inside wash him outside

Comment: What's a "shower horse"?

Comment: Sounds like a bad seating of the O-rings on the shower valve's cartridges, if I had to take a guess... (or straight up broken). Changes in pressure may seat or un-seat it even if it's on or off. Have fun with that... there's nothing like buying some new cartridges just to find out you should've redone the whole valve... but having to do that is *way* less fun.

Comment: City water or well? Either way, what's the pressure at?

Answer (score 1):

Your shower valve is supposed to be able to be turned off completely. If you have a pressure balancing shower valve that will not turn off, then I suppose that lowering the pressure in one or the other of the hot or the cold line (which is what would happen if you open a valve elsewhere) could cause water to flow through the shower valve. Is the flow from the shower hot or cold water? Does the flow from the shower happen if you draw cold water elsewhere or hot water or either?

The solution would be to disassemble the shower valve and see if you can find a fault and if necessary check the adjustment of the pressure balancing.

**EDIT**

However, since it is some trouble to disassemble these valves you should thoroughly investigate the matter before taking that step. It has been reported that some "washerless" faucets actually use the pressure to seal and so leak when the pressure gets low. If this is what is happening with this shower valve, then you don't want to disassemble it. You need to do some testing to better define the conditions under which the shower delivers water when it is "off".

Comment: I have seen when the water pressure is low (caused by turning on another tap) some "washerless" faucets do this they actually use the pressure to seal.

Comment: So the shower valve could be functioning as designed and this user just has very low water pressure?

Comment: I believe that may be the cause Jim, add that to your answer and I will pivoted I think your answer could also be correct that's why I put a comment.